# foreach перезаписывает элементы массива

Tags: php, symfony2, foreach

Цикл foreach почему-то перезаписывает результат последнего выполнения дважды.

Исходный код:

```
$functions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Functions')->findBy(Array('triggerid'=>$trigger->getTriggerid()));
        dump($functions);
$i=1;
    $out->functions=array();
    foreach ($functions as $function)
    {


        $out_function->function=$function->getFunction();



        $out_function->parameter=$function->getParameter();
        $out_function->functionid=$function->getFunctionid();
       dump($out_function);



        $out->functions[$i]=$out_function;


        $i++;
        dump($out);




    }
```

Вывод дампа:

Функции полученные по условию:

```
 array:2 [▼
0 => Functions {#3833 ▶}
1 => Functions {#3928 ▶}
]
```

Как мы видим их **две**

Вывод $out_function в цикле foreach (1ая итерация)

```
{#3495 ▼
+"function": "str"
+"parameter": "Tunnel,#1"
+"functionid": "36521"
}
```

Вывод $out (1ая итерация) -

```
{#3494 ▼
+"expression": "{36521}=1 and {36522}>8000000"
+"issue": ">80% утилизация вход GigabitEthernet0/0.204"
+"lastchange": 0
+"status": 0
+"priority": 2
+"triggerid": "30233"
+"ack": "0"
+"functions": array:1 [▼
  1 => {#3495 ▼
    +"function": "str"
    +"parameter": "Tunnel,#1"
    +"functionid": "36521"
  }
]
}
```

Затем считывает вторую функцию -

```
{#3495 ▼
+"function": "last"
+"parameter": "#2"
+"functionid": "36522"
}
```

..И записывает её в массив **дважды**, при этом перезаписывая первый элемент:

```
{#3494 ▼
+"expression": "{36521}=1 and {36522}>8000000"
+"issue": ">80% утилизация вход GigabitEthernet0/0.204"
+"lastchange": 0
+"status": 0
+"priority": 2
+"triggerid": "30233"
+"ack": "0"
+"functions": array:2 [▼
  1 => {#3495 ▼
    +"function": "last"
    +"parameter": "#2"
    +"functionid": "36522"
  }
  2 => {#3495 ▶}
]
}
```

Comment: где объявлена $out_function

Comment: '$out_function= new \stdClass();'

(объявлена не в цикле)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Темное у вас там дело с переменной `$out_function` Непонятно откуда берется этот объект как он инициализируется и вообще.

А собственно сам эффект заключается в том то в массив `$out->function` добавляется ссылка на объект, а не его копия. И по сути меняя объект вы меняете и данные по первой ссылке.

Возможно лечится это тем, что `$out_function` инициализируется внутри foreach

P.S.: и очень желательно бы знать версию PHP на которой это все происходит. Это может быть ключевым моментом.

Comment: `$out_function= new \stdClass();`
объявляется не в цикле.

Попробую исправить